# Hair Dynamics not colliding with emitter 2.75a

Tags: objects, physics, particles

I'm currently working on a character model, and the tutorials I'm working from use a slightly older version of Blender (2.73, I believe?).

The Hair Dynamics tab in 2.75a is substantially different, and appears much less intuitive. When it bakes the hair dynamics, there is no collision with the actual emitter mesh (i.e., that character); it simply falls into the mesh.

I've tried adjusting the physics parameters in the emitter mesh for soft body and cloth with no result, and all the tutorials I've found on YouTube thus far are for hair particles colliding with meshes other than the emitter.

How do I enable the hair to collide with the emitter mesh?

Answer (score 1):

The previous hair system calculated mass much differently, so by reducing the mass significantly (from 1.0 to 0.1), the hair didn't fall through the mesh in as many places. Tweaking the mass seems to help fix the issue, although weight painting the hair strands is required and tweaking the collision properties of the emitter.