# Blender Cycles How to have hair not go through mesh *WITH HAIR DYNAMICS*

Tags: hair

I have been searching everywhere but couldn't find an answer, but basically I have a model and I added hair dynamics and a wind that has strength of 2, noise and flow of 1. The hair keeps going through the mesh and I don't know why, please help! Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6487/make-rigid-body-collide-with-hair-particles and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35109/hair-dynamics-not-colliding-with-emitter-2-75a

Comment: Those are different, here I'm using only one mesh, not two.

Comment: Can anyone help me??

Answer (score 0):

In a newer version of Blender, this was fixed. Now all you have to do is add a collision modifier/physics property to the emitter object and the hair emitted will collide with the emitter.